# MyApp "instance has no attribute 'var'" error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an app where the user is supposed to pick an option and then the value will be printed once the button is pressed.  However I get the error `AttributeError: MyApp instance has no attribute 'var'` when I try to run this.  Any thoughts?

```
class MyApp(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)  

        self.execute = Button(root, text="Convert", command=self.convert())
        self.execute.grid(row=4, column=3, pady=9, padx=3)

        self.var = StringVar()
        rb1 = Checkbutton(root, text="Path", variable=self.var, offvalue='marker', onvalue='path')#, value='path'
        rb1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=3, sticky=W)
        rb2 = Checkbutton(root, text="Markers", variable=self.var, offvalue='path', onvalue='marker')
        rb2.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=3, sticky=W)

    def convert(self):
        print self.var.get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
self.execute = Button(root, text="Convert", command=self.convert())
```

You are calling `self.convert` because of the trailing `()`, and this method depends on `self.var`, but you haven't set `self.var` yet.

You need to remove the `()`:

```
self.execute = Button(root, text="Convert", command=self.convert)
```

Comment: geeze...Such a simple fix.  Thanks for the help!  I had been messing with this problem for WAY too long.